# Pull in document library views using a web part

Tags: document-library

Is there a web part for SharePoint 2010 that can be dropped on a page and automatically pull in all available views from a specific document library (ideally be restricted per instance though) - to allow the user to quickly view all available documents and select a range of views?

Answer (score 1):

You can always drop the default document library web part on the page and configure it to show the full toolbar. This will display a view selector similar to the 2007 interface.

Another way would be to drop multiple web parts for the library on the page, set each of them to a different view and use EasyTabs (http://www.pathtosharepoint.com/sharepoint-user-toolkit/Pages/Easy-Tabs-v5.aspx) to tab them.

Of course, if the library resides in another site, this is another issue.